# Restart crashed executable when multiple instance of the same is running

Tags: c#, wcf, process, crash

I have developed an application (.NET C#) for document processing and below is the application's architecture:

[image]

My application uses SQL Server, WCF Windows Service, Indexer and Processing.exe. When user start processing documents, Service launches Processing.exe with specific parameters like which documents to process and which user has requested processing. There are multiple users using application so Service can start Processing.exe multiple times as per requirements.

Now, one of Processing.exe crashes without completing the task! So my question is... How can we restart that one particular Processing.exe when it crashes? Or can we get notification that process is crashed? In short, How can we manage this?

Comment: You will need an extra process / service that detects whether Processing.exe has crashed (and if it has, start it again).

Comment: As you have to provide a report of your service, my idea is to allow Processing.exe to access that report and say what it does and if it did successfully or if it fails, why ..., so the service will know if it needs to restart or not and may count the number of attempts ...